# How to implement a Jquery slider with multiple handles that detect collision with each other?

Tags: collision, detection, uislider

I have a jquery slider that contains a handle for each item in a given array.

I want each slider to detect when it has collided with any other handle. When I say collided I mean overlapped because I do want them to actually overlap.

I have created this but I am sure there is a simpler way to write this comparison 'if' statement. Can someone please suggest an alternative?

***Please read the note at the bottom before answering this question.**

```
var handle_data = {point:'2',point:'4',point:'6',point:'8'}; // will contain other data later
var handle_points = []; 
$.each(handle_data, function(i, val){               
    handle_points.push(val["point"]);
});

$("#slider").slider({
    values: slider_points,
    slide: function(evt, ui) {
        if (
        ui.values[0] == ui.values[1]||
        ui.values[0] == ui.values[2]||
        ui.values[0] == ui.values[3]||
        ui.values[0] == ui.values[4]||
        ui.values[1] == ui.values[2]||
        ui.values[1] == ui.values[3]||
        ui.values[1] == ui.values[4]||
        ui.values[2] == ui.values[4]||
        ui.values[2] == ui.values[3]||
        ui.values[3] == ui.values[4])
        console.log('collsion');
    }
});
```

**Note:**
In the end the handles will have varied widths then I will need two types of collision detection.

1) If dragging handle becomes overlapped partially with any other handle, Do..
2) If dragging handle's centre point overlaps or crosses another handle's centre point, Do..

I'm not sure if this will hugely effect the answer to my original problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function check_overlap() {
ARE_overlaped=[], NOT_overlaped=[];
$('.ui-slider-handle').each(function(i, obj0) {

    $('.ui-slider-handle').not(obj0).each(function(i, obj1) {
        left = $(this).offset().left;
        overlap = !($(obj0).offset().left + $(obj0).width() < $(this).offset().left || $(obj0).offset().left > $(this).offset().left + $(this).width());
        (overlap) ? overlap = true : overlap = false;
        return !overlap;
    });

    (overlap) ? ARE_overlaped.push($(this).attr("id")):NOT_overlaped.push($(this).attr("id"));  

    if(ARE_overlaped.length > 0) overlap = true;
    if(NOT_overlaped.length ==0) overlap = false;
    $(ARE_overlaped).each(function(){ 
        $('#'+this).addClass('overlap');
        $('#'+this).find('.info').html('<div class="warning red"></div>');
    });
    $(NOT_overlaped).each(function(){ 
        $('#'+this).removeClass('overlap');
        $('#'+this).find('.info .red').removeClass('warning red');
        if($('#'+this).position().left==$('#'+this).attr("origleft")) $('#'+this).find('.info').html('');
    });
});
$('#result').text('Overlap: ' + overlap); // FOR TESTING display overlap status
}
```